# Schema.ini have to be enter a blank line at the top

Tags: sql, database, import, oledb

Today, I was found a problem with schema.ini, here is my example:

Query:
SELECT *
FROM  OpenDataSource('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Data Source="C:\Temp\";User ID=;Password=;Extended properties="Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited()"')...[ve01#csv]

ve01.csv file content:

```
Record No.|Sales Target Link
00000000|00000000
00000001|00000000
00000002|00000003
00000003|00000007
00000004|00000008
00000005|00000000
```

schema.ini file:

```
---------------------------
[VE01.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=Delimited(|)
TextDelimiter=
Col1=Record_No Text
Col2=Sales_Target_Link Text
---------------------------
```

The query will return data correctly seperated by (|) if I add a blank line at the top of schema.ini like below:

```
---------------------------

[VE01.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=Delimited(|)
TextDelimiter=
Col1=Record_No Text
Col2=Sales_Target_Link Text
---------------------------
```

Can someone please help? 
Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry guys, my question is: If I don't add a blank line at the top of schema file, it won't return data correctly with columns defined in there.

Comment: Anyway, I found out the case: it's about the Encoding of schema.ini file, I have to change it to UTF-8 (it was UTF-8 BOM etc...)